# Flow type not saving static props in HOC

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, higher-order-components

I'm running into an issue where I can pass either a class or a functional component into my HOC. In the HOC I need to access a static property on the component that is being passed in(PAGE). The problem here is that FLOW is giving me an error saying it can't find the static properties on the PAGE that is being passed into the HOC:

`Error:(50, 21) Flow: property getInitialProps. Property not found in statics of React$Component`.

That error is coming from this line in the code below:

```
const pageProps =
            (await Page.getInitialProps) && (await Page.getInitialProps(ctx))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - My full hoc:

```
type DefaultProps = {
      getInitialProps: (ctx:any) => any
    }

type FunctionComponent<P> = (props: P) => ?React.Element<*>;
type ClassComponent<D, P, S> = Class<React.Component<D, P, S>>;

type Component<D, P> = FunctionComponent<P> | ClassComponent<D, P, any>;

export default <D: DefaultProps, P: {}, S: {}> (Page: Component<D, P>, title: string = '') => {
  class standardLayout extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps (ctx) {



// Flow can't read getInitialProps
   const pageProps = Page.getInitialProps ? (await Page.getInitialProps(ctx)) : await Page.getInitialProps

      return {
        ...pageProps,
        currentUrl: ctx.pathname
      }
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <div>

          <Page {...this.props} />

        </div>
      )
    }
  }

  return connect()(standardLayout)
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's because `getInitialProps` is not a property but a method. Your `(await Page.getInitialProps)` is really strange, what did you expect to get here ? If you want to check if `getInitialProps` exists, then `const pageProps = Page.getInitialProps && (await Page.getInitialProps(ctx))` should be enough

Comment: @soywod thanks for the help! I took your advice and changed it - now these 2 errors pop up -> 
Error:(50, 55) Flow: call of method `getInitialProps`. Function cannot be called on property `getInitialProps` of unknown type -- second error -> Error:(50, 90) Flow: property `getInitialProps` of unknown type. This type is incompatible with union: type application of class `Promise` | type parameter `T` of await. I thought setting getInitialProps to a Function would be enough..

Comment: `getInitialProps: Function` where does `Function` come from ?

Comment: @soywod - Function is a generic Prop type for es6, not sure if that is 100% compatible with flow though....

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found to get rid of this error is to check if `Page.getInitialProps` is a function. A simple `typeof Page.getInitialProps === 'function'`, or a `try ... catch` worked for me, Flow was happy. But I still not understand why this : `const pageProps = Page.getInitialProps ? (await Page.getInitialProps(ctx)) : await Page.getInitialProps` ? You can't do this `await Page.getInitialProps`, just replace it by `null` or `{}`

Comment: Thats what I thought too but if I just pass the FunctionalComponent - the getInitialProps does not throw an error - but now the HOC cannot take a React Component as a parameter.

Comment: Yea your right Page.getInitialProps doesn't make sense. I'm using next.js and got that from an example for using an HOC - so I'll see if that makes any difference. Using the function check was a great idea! Thank you so much!!